# I can't set width and height of video player - livecode

Tags: livecode

I want to set width and height of my video player.

Here my code.

```
         put the text of fld "txt_width" into w_value
         put the text of fld "txt_height" into h_value
         set the width of player ID idplayer of stack stackname to w_value
         set the height of player ID idplayer of stack stackname to h_value
```

And I set autoplay on opencard.Before autoplay video.Width and Height is working.After opencard and video play.Width and Height of video is resize to original.

How do I do ?

Comment: what exactly your code is can you add over here?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the lockLocation of the player object to true to stop the player resizing automatically;

```
set the lockLocation of player id idPlayer to true
```